# rspec routing with subdomain

Tags: subdomain, rspec-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm having a Rails 5 api only app using rspec and versioned this way :

```
app
  - controllers
    - api
      - v1 
        - users_controller.rb
```

My `api/v1/users_controller.rb` :

```
module Api::V1
  class UsersController < ApiController
```

My `config\routes.rb` :

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  constraints subdomain: 'api' do
    scope module: 'api' do
      namespace :v1 do
        resources :users
      end
    end
  end
end
```

When I check the routes with `rails routes` it shows me.

```
  Prefix Verb   URI Pattern             Controller#Action
v1_users GET    /v1/users(.:format)     api/v1/users#index {:subdomain=>"api"}
         POST   /v1/users(.:format)     api/v1/users#create {:subdomain=>"api"}
 v1_user GET    /v1/users/:id(.:format) api/v1/users#show {:subdomain=>"api"}
         PATCH  /v1/users/:id(.:format) api/v1/users#update {:subdomain=>"api"}
         PUT    /v1/users/:id(.:format) api/v1/users#update {:subdomain=>"api"}
         DELETE /v1/users/:id(.:format) api/v1/users#destroy {:subdomain=>"api"}
```

My spec file :

```
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe Api::V1::UsersController, type: :routing do
  describe "routing" do

    it "routes to #index" do
      expect(:get => "/v1/users").to route_to("api/v1/users#index")
    end

    it "routes to #create" do
      expect(:post => "/v1/users").to route_to("api/v1/users#create")
    end

    it "routes to #show" do
      expect(:get => "/v1/users/1").to route_to("api/v1/users#show", :id => "1")
    end

    it "routes to #update via PUT" do
      expect(:put => "/v1/users/1").to route_to("api/v1/users#update", :id => "1")
    end

    it "routes to #update via PATCH" do
      expect(:patch => "/v1/users/1").to route_to("api/v1/users#update", :id => "1")
    end

    it "routes to #destroy" do
      expect(:delete => "/v1/users/1").to route_to("api/v1/users#destroy", :id => "1")
    end

  end
end
```

But when I'm testing my routes with rspec it fails as it.

```
 bundle exec rspec spec/routing/users_routing_spec.rb
FFFFF

Failures:

  1) Api::V1::UsersController routing routes to #index
     Failure/Error: expect(:get => "/v1/users").to route_to("api/v1/users#index")
       No route matches "/v1/users"
     # ./spec/routing/users_routing_spec.rb:7:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I don't understand why. Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify "subdomain" for your spec.

```
before do
  Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = 'test.host'
end

it "routes to #index" do
  expect(:get => v1_users_url).to route_to('v1/users#index', subdomain: 'api')
end
```